# How to update tag in youtube using youtube api v3 in c#

Tags: c#, youtube-data-api

I am creating console application which update tag field for specific video in you tube using c#.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work :

```
 video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
```

This would remove any existing TAGS for the video and assign a new array.

or you can just use ADD method to add a new one :

```
video.Snippet.Tags.Add("item2");
```

reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet

Comment: you all right but when i update tags at that time i am getting insufficient error to update tags. Error code : 403

Comment: my error code is :                                                                                 Error: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Insufficient Permission [403]
Errors [
        Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
]

Comment: Permission issues for any changes. Refer to this code to locate what you are missing- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36856/Professional-Tag-Editor-for-MP-ID-and-WMA